# Como generar que los dots tengan ese funcionamiento con OWL Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Que opción dentro del plugin owl carousel debo modificar para generar ese efecto en los dots.

[image: Dots customizados]

Comment: ¿Ya revisaste la [documentación](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-welcome.html). Aparte, con una imagen no es posible ayudarte, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código que estás usando y explicar exactamente cuál es el problema.

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por tu respuesta. Dejo link de owl carousel demo de la misma página. Es tal cual. La misma estructura. https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html

Comment: Si tu código es igual al del enlace debería funcionar exactamente igual. Si no, simplemente cópialo y adáptalo a tus necesidades.

Comment: Si claro funciona igual eso no es lo que pido como ayuda. Lo que necesito es saber como puedo hacer que los dots tengan el mismo diseño al funcionar es decir que vaya de un tamaño menor a mayor segun roten los dots.